# VBA: Function Cells inside IsEmpty

Tags: vba, excel

can you help me with this VBA code. I think what is wrong is the Cells function inside the IsEmpty function, that is the line that is Excel is accusing to be wrong. I have made some changes due to the comments, but it still is not running. The problem is with the line that is the IsEmpty function.

```
    Sub preenche_lacunas()

Dim linha_um As Integer
Dim linha_inicio As Integer
Dim linha_final As Integer
Dim coluna_um As Integer
Dim coluna_inicio As Integer
Dim coluna_final As Integer
Dim preenche_com As Integer    


    linha_inicio = 5
    linha_final = 101

    coluna_inicio = 2
    coluna_final = 16

    preenche_com = 0

    linha_um = linha_inicio
    Do While (linha_um <= linha_final)

        coluna_um = coluna_inicio
        Do While (coluna_um <= coluna_final)

            If IsEmpty(Cells(linha_um, coluna_um)) Then

                Cells(linha_um, coluna_um) = preenche_com
            End If

            coluna_um = coluna_um + 1
        Loop

        linha_um = linha_um + 1
    Loop

    End Sub
```

Comment: You just need to set `linha_um = linha_inicio` before the `Do While...` because the first time you use `Cells` then `linha_um` will be 0.

Comment: you are missing the `linha_um = linha_um + 1` and outer `Loop`

Comment: 1. Don't try and assign a number to a cell's .Value2 property, just assign it to the cell; e.g. `Cells(linha_um, coluna_um) = preenche_com` 2. Qualify the parent worksheet. A With .. End With might be best here. 3. Use `Option Explicit` and declare your vars (see [ALWAYS Use "Option Explicit"](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit#t=201704261430228061084).

Comment: Scott, yes I do. It was a copy and past mistake. I will correct it but that isn't the problem

Comment: Thanks Peh and Jeeped

Comment: If you are trying to prep a worksheet for some other operation like importing into SQL then you need to revert the formulas that return zero-length strings to their underlying values then cycle through each column with TextToColumns, Fixed Width, Finish to create truly blank cells. These will import into SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to loop through *linha* (i.e. *rows*) from 5 to 101 and *coluna* (i.e. *columns*) from B to P (2 to 16) and put a zero in any blank cell.

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    with .range(.cells(5, 2), .cells(101, 16))
        'make sure that .UsedRange extends at least as far as the extents
        if isempty(.cells(.rows.count, .columns.count)) then _
            .cells(.rows.count, .columns.count) = 0
        'skip over if there are no blank cells
        on error resume next
        .specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks) = 0
        'reset standard error protocol
        on error goto 0
    end with
end with
```

Remember that cells containing zero-length strings (e.g. `""` or `TEXT(,)` from a formula) are not truly blank.

Comment: Thank you @Jeeped, help me a lot! Why did you put periods in front of most functions?

Comment: ... because using `with worksheets("Sheet1")` means that .Range and  .Cells in `.range(.cells(5, 2), .cells(101, 16))` belong to Sheet1. For the same reason, .Cells, .Rows.Count and .SpecialCells inside `with .range(.cells(5, 2), .cells(101, 16))` belong to .range(.cells(5, 2), .cells(101, 16)).

Comment: Ok, got it. But then why doesn't my code work? Why is `If IsEmpty(Cells(linha_um, coluna_um)) Then

                Cells(linha_um, coluna_um) = preenche_com
            End If ` wrong?

Comment: I honestly do not know why your code (from the latest edit) does not work. I tried it and even threw a forced `#DIV/0!` error into the worksheet but `IsEmpty` skipped over it and completed its task.

Answer (score 0):

Change to below to get the column number:

```
coluna_inicio = Columns("B").Column
coluna_final = Columns("P").Column
```